# Pass a struct to a class method

Tags: objective-c, struct, class-method

I wanted to be able to do this:

```
vec2 pos(1,5);
myActor.position = [Coord positionFrom: pos ];
```

Using my structure:

```
typedef float32 float;
struct vec2 {
    vec2(float32 xx, float32 yy) {
        x = xx;
        y = yy;
    }
    float32 x, y;
};
```

Coord.h

```
@interface Coord : NSObject {
}
+(CGPoint) positionFrom: (vec2) pos;
+(CGPoint) positionFromAngle: (float32) angle;
```

Coord.mm

```
#import "Coord.h"
@implementation Coord
+(CGPoint) positionFrom:(vec2) pos {
    return CGPointMake( pos.x * 32, pos.y * 32);
}
+(CGPoint) positionFromAngle:(float32) angle {
    return CGPointMake( cos(angle) * 32, cos(angle) * 32);
}
@end
```

But I get these errors (in Coord.h, on the positionFrom lines):

```
Expected ')' before 'vec2'
Expected ')' before 'float32'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be:

```
+(CGPoint) positionFrom: (struct vec2) pos;
```

Or else you have failed to import the header file that defines `vec2`.

You also have a trailing `]` in the `return` statement of `positionFrom:`.

BTW, just stylistically, this kind of thing is usually done with a function rather than a class method. Something like this:

```
CGPoint CGPointFromVec2( struct vec2 pos );
```

That makes it parallel to `CGPointFromString()`.

Comment: The trailing `]` was a typo so I've removed it.  Adding the struct keyword fixed it - I've added another function which gives basically the same error, but I'm unsure how to fix that

Comment: You've used typedef backwards. You've defined "float" to be of type "float32" and then not defined float32 anywhere. You may still be forgetting to import the header file that defines your struct and typedefs.